# PHP When a user registers, How do I add their details to the end of an existing CSV file?

Tags: php, csv

I'm creating a website for my school computing project. Due to the school not having the ability to use mySQL or SQLite, I am having to use CSV files.

My problem is I have already created a CSV file with values i've manually entered for testing, I want to be able to add the details a user enters to the end of that same CSV file.

**Users.csv:**

```
ID,Username,Email,DateOfBirth,Password,UserScore
1,Test,Test@Test.com,01/01/2000,Test,10
2,Alfie,Alfie@gmail.com,22/02/1000,1234,0
```

**Current PHP code:**

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $submittype = $_POST['submit'];     
        if($submittype == "register" && (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['dateOfBirth']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['confirmPassword']))) {
            die("ERROR|Please fill out all of the fields.");
        } else {
            $userID = 0; //TODO: Increment
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $dateOfBirth = $_POST['dateOfBirth'];
            $confirmPassword = $_POST['confirmPassword'];
            $userScore = 0;

            $data = $userID.",".$username.",".$email.",".$dateOfBirth.",".$password.",".$userScore;
            $file = fopen('Users.csv','a');
            fputcsv($file, $data);
            fclose($file);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your code? Any error?

Comment: fputcsv expects an array, not a csv-string. That's what the error message said, isn't it?

Comment: @mario ok, I don't seem to get any error message though

Comment: Then why don't you enable them when obviously something doesn't work?

Comment: You could just read the hole content, append the new user using string concatenation and insert the hole content overwriting the old one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `array` instead of `string`, when you use `fputcsv`. I've also incremented the `$userId` with this line: `$userId = count(file($file));` It reads the file lines into an array, count it, so it will always increments.

I've also improved your code a littlebit, with clear thos unused variables. You can use `$_POST["anything"]` directly, you do not need to create another variable, what you do not manipulate.

Check this.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $submittype = $_POST['submit'];
    if ($submittype == "register" && (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['dateOfBirth']) || empty($_POST['password']) || empty($_POST['confirmPassword']))) {
        die("ERROR|Please fill out all of the fields.");
    } else {
        $file = 'Users.csv';
        $userId = count(file($file)); 
        //$userID = 0; //TODO: Increment
        $userScore = 0;
        $data = array($userId, $_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["password"], $_POST["dateOfBirth"], $_POST["confirmPassword"], 0);
        $fh = fopen($file, 'a');
        fputcsv($fh, $data, ",");
        fclose($fh);
    }
}
```

There is an alternative way, check `MBaas`s answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   $file = fopen('Users.csv','a');
    fputcsv($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
```

with this:

```
file_put_contents('Users.csv' , $data . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
```